# Delphi XE2 future

Tags: delphi, native, delphi-xe2

I am an independent consultant and I have developed a product which is liked by my customer that I am trying to port from Java to Delphi. Delphi satisfies couple of my important needs: Native code compilation that gives speed and obfuscation and the language is highly productive as I tried.

Question that I have is:

1. Would you invest in Delphi, given its turbulent past?
2. Is there any alternative to Delphi if I want to chose a platform that compiles to native code and is portable to MAC and highly productive?

Comment: The fact is that if Delphi never got another update again, it'd still be an _excellent_ platform for many many years.

Comment: cross platform delphi has potential but the new firemonkey platform is still a long way from being ready for primetime

Comment: I would recommend sticking with Java if possible, you're more productive with it and rather than following the learning curve(which can be quite long) you would be better investing in the product itself.

Delphi is good for Windows platform, but it will take quite some time to be an alternative for other platforms. Don't get me wrong, Delphi puts food on my table, but if you can stick with Java, I would highly recommend it. If you really want to use Delphi for Mac, then you should analyze very carefully if it will suit ALL your needs before you start working in it.

Comment: On stackoverflow we call these questions "shark versus gorilla" questions. They have no objective answer, and tend to provoke only subjective opinion.  I am almost never in favor of porting a working product towards or away from any language that is not completely dead, unless you want to be dead-in-the-water for six months or a year it takes to rewrite your existing app completely. There is no guarantee that you will do a better job in your rewrite (see Brooks, Second System Effect, in the Mythical Man Month).

Answer (score 5):

1. Does a turbulent past necessarily mean a turbulent future? Look at the current state of Delphi as it has been since Embarcadero took over and evaluate based on that.
2. Apparently your other choices might be [C# .NET with Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), C++ with a cross-platform GUI library such as [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), or Java. But it's a subjective call as to whether one would call those "highly productive".

There's [a nice Squidoo article on Cross Platform GUI Programming](http://www.squidoo.com/crossplatformgui) that will give you some things to consider in your choice, and it lists a few other possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

The latest Delphi XE2 supports cross-platform native development for Windows 32bit and 64bit, Mac OSX 32bit, and iOS with its new FireMonkey framework.

If you don't want to use Delphi, you can use FreePascal (which Delphi uses internally for its iOS support until a native iOS compiler is created).

Comment: Did not know that Delphi uses FreePascal internally for iOS support. Thanks for that info!

Comment: It is only a temporary solution to get iOS support to market while the next-gen compiler is being worked on.

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly highly recommend using Delphi if you are in consideration of its abilities. Especially with the release of RAD studio XE2, where you can compile 32/64bit/mac/mobile apps, you'll be impressed at the capabilities. I regret to say that I'm not that familiar with many other languages, but I have basically come to be extremely comfortable with Delphi.

If I had to compare it with another language, I'd have to say C#, which Delphi is pretty much the Father language of C#. Delphi is great for pure lower-level programming, whereas C# seems to have an extra layer over it (including .NET). C# is widely used in .NET applications such as websites (ASP.NET), windows forms applications, service applications, etc.

Both Delphi and C# can pretty much do the same thing, but in a different approach (and far different syntax). I'm not sure however if C# can be used on MAC platforms. But Microsoft Visual Studio is the software you want for C#.

I also recommend that you point your interest in FireMonkey, which comes with XE2. This is an HD application language. It's basically a re-write of the entire VCL library for better graphics, and much more.

Comment: I dont think the syntax is THAT different between C# and Delphi. And similarly im not entirely convinced VS is THE software for C#. Personally i think its a bit of a bloated dog.

Comment: I think you meant Java when describing the language ancestry. WinForms is clearly related to VCL but that's not what you said. If you want x-plat C# then mono is what is required.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: wrt ancestry C#'s mother is Java and its father is Delphi (I trust you are aware that C#'s designer and Delphi's designer are one and the same?). In fact you could say that C# was intended to take the good things from both languages and leave behind the bad...

Comment: @marjan which parts of C# language are closely inspired by Delphi? I have to saw I had not noticed the similarity. C# to mind mind is Java done right.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Some might say that 'Java done right' is 'Delphi with enhancements'. Just had C# course and have to say it was almost entirely an "Aha" erlebnis. And this was more so for "Delphians" than for people coming from Java/C/C++ backgrounds. Reading and writing C# just feels natural to me, whereas reading Java and C/C++ always feels very awkward. As far as Delphi inspired constructs go: I'm afraid I can't point to anything specific. Perhaps the inspiration from Delphi comes more in the spirit of the language (make it hard to make errors) than in its constructs.

Comment: @Downvoter please explain how my answer is "Not Useful"